# Jquery ajax error causing infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

When a user tabs into a text box on a page it fires off the onfocus event to call a web service via jquery AJAX call.

If there is an error with the ajax call, I want to display a message to the user via an alert box but it is causing an infinite loop.  It will display the alert box, the user clicks okay and the alert box reappears.

How do I resolve this issue?

```
function DoSomething() {
    var url = baseUrl + "/MyMethod";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { input: 'MyData' },
        error: function(e) {
            alert("Display message");
        }
    });
}

<asp:Textbox id="txtMyTextBox" runat="server" onfocus="DoSomething" />
```

Comment: don't use alert and the input won't lose focus.

Comment: Well you would either need to remove the focus event or find a better way to show the message to the user so focus does not need to be removed.

Comment: When an alert pops up, the textbox loses focus. When the alert is gone, the focus is regained, and the function is run again.

Comment: From a UI perspective this is not a good way to manage interaction. I personally would not like a website that removes focus from elements when an error has occured, much like how using an `alert` typically isn't good practice either. OP should probably either not bind this function to `blur`, or if he does, put the error message inline and retain focus on the element.

Comment: I have removed the alert, wrote the message to a div and it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Bind to an actual user action like `onclick` or `onchange`, instead of `onfocus`. If the user hasn't entered anything, there's probably nothing useful to send to the server, right?

```
<asp:Textbox id="txtMyTextBox" runat="server" onclick="DoSomething" />
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, it's a comment/question

Comment: It's a simple answer to the question, plus a bonus comment/question. But I added a code snippet for you.